# Travis CI - limited number of pulled commits from github

Tags: git, github, travis-ci

I am moving to Travis CI. Previously I was creating build numbers from the number of all commits:

```
build_num=`git rev-list HEAD --count`
```

This was matching github's number of commits.

This doesn't work when calulated by a script on Travis CI. It gives a different number which even tends to decrease with additional commits.

Looks like Travis CI is only taking 50 last commits into consideration.

Comment: how about using travis CI build number?

Comment: not good since I do builds not only by travis, so that will not hold the consistency.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is happening is that travis is pulling github repo with depth=50:

```
$ git clone --depth=50 --branch=master
```

Travis provides non public API for changing this setting:

https://twitter.com/travisci/status/288390896339267584

So adding:

```
git:
  depth: 10000
```

fixed the problem.

Comment: Please remember to return and accept your answer (I think as a low rep user you have to wait 2 days first though).